# .Net HttpWebResponse Via HTTPS Response Stream - Works with Fiddler - Garbage Without

Tags: .net, https, httpwebrequest, fiddler, httpwebresponse

I am new to this but so far have been able to find the answers to all of my questions except this one! Pulling my hair out here.

The situation is this:

A) Getting an **httpWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()** from an **HTTPS** site (no login, just encrypted traffic) **works *with Fiddler running*** and decrypting HTTPS traffic.

B) Getting an **httpWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()** from an **HTTPS** site (no login, just encrypted traffic) **gives me jibberish (garbage) *without Fiddler running*** as if the stream is either encrypted or encoded.

Server returns 200 OK in both cases; this happens on the response after the POST of some data (the initial webRequest - starting page - to the HTTPS site returns a readable stream both with and without Fiddler running).

I have no idea what to do from here.  I know that the stream should be automatically decrypted and decoded but I guess it is not.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Much thanks.

Comment: Are you turning off Fiddler while HTTPS session is running?

Comment: Anybody? Please?  If the question is unclear, please let me know and I will try my best to clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure what happened here (lack of detail on my part / lack of community interest / etc.), but I finally found the answer myself after installing Wireshark and looking at different scenarios.

For those interested, it turned out that Fiddler automatically decompressed the "page" returned by the server before passing to the end client.  I was not decompressing in my code (didn't know I should) and thus the problem.  As for the initial webrequest being fine, I did not specify an encoding for it and thus the server responded with an uncompressed "page" (I specified an encoding on all subsequent requests).

And there it is.

Comment: Fiddler will only decode a response if you tell it to; the most common way to do that is to use the AutoDecode toolbar button.

Comment: I guess I must have set that option initially on first start and forgot all about it (to me, it is not obvious that it is even on).